# How to render new jsp page from ajax call to Spring Controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, jsp

I am using Spring I have

Anchor tags list like below and i need to make post call so i used ajax query.

```
<td><a href="#" onclick='doAjax(${taskDetail.taskId})'> ${taskDetail.taskTitle}</a></td>
```

in my same jsp i have ajax call as below

```
function doAjax(x) {

    alert(x);

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getTaskDetail",
    data: { taskId: x }
       }
    })
  }
```

now my controller has

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getTaskDetail", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String getTaskDetail(@RequestParam String taskId, Model model) {
    System.out.println("i am herer......");

        try {


            TaskDet taskDet = getTaskinformation(Integer.parseInt(taskId));


            model.addAttribute("taskDet", taskDet);

            return "showtaskpage";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                        }
    }
```

now my "showtaskpage" itself is .jsp page.

now the problem is that , everything works like charm , but when it returns showtaskpage, it is not getting rentered in new jsp page , I am still in the previous page and when i click this anchor link , it goes to the controller and get response but i will get .jsp full page as data format , we can see it using firebug.

I want to be shown as `http://localhost:8080/mydummy/showtaskpage`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you mean to say the url should also be changed with ajax request success?

Comment: I want to get the new jsp page that is showtaskpage ,

Comment: right now it is staying in the same page without showing my jsp page.

Comment: So in your controller then you have to return the `MAV` which is your new page you are requesting.

Comment: could you please give me MAV example , i really dont how to keep the .jsp page in the MAV , signature.

Comment: That is fine but you wont be able to change the url but you can take the jsp view in your current page.

Comment: MAV is not working at all same thing happening..

Answer (score 4):

I have modified as below

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "getTaskDetail",
data: { taskId: x },
success : function(data) {
    alert('success');
    document.open();
    document.write(data);
    document.close();
}
})
```

now i what happens is it will render as new JSP page working .

Comment: Thank you, great answer!

Answer (score 0):

The way of return ModelAndView

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getTaskDetail", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getTaskDetail(@RequestParam String taskId, ModelAndView mav) {
    System.out.println("i am herer......");

    if (!user.isAuthenticated()) {
        mav.setViewName("redirect:http://localhost:8080/mydummy/showtaskpage");
        return mav;
    }

    mav.setViewName("showtaskpage");
    mav.addObject("wxyz", listService.getLists());

    return mav;
}
```

The way of return String

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getTaskDetail", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getTaskDetail(@RequestParam String taskId, ModelAndView mav) {

    if (!user.isAuthenticated()) {
        return "redirect:http://localhost:8080/mydummy/showtaskpage";
    }

    model.addAttribute("wxyz", listService.getLists());

    return "showtaskpage";
}
```

Comment: the secound code will not render new jsp , it shows in the same jsp file.

Comment: POST http://localhost:8080/timemantra/getTaskDetail
 
from firefox using firebug , this the POST call happened and response was 200 OK 32ms and i can see the showtaskpage jsp page in the response.

Comment: _i can see the showtaskpage jsp page in the response._ now you need to place the view in your page with ajax success handler.

Comment: I want to show in completely new page , not in the same page.

Comment: One more thing for this i think you need to use type GET.